# Why is my program for, minimum difference between ANY TWO elements in an array, giving opposite result?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

This might sound like a repeat question but it is not because I haven't found the answer to my question in-spite of going through several references/related questions as listed below (and a lot more not listed).

[Minimum difference in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505426/minimum-difference-in-an-array)

[Finding out the minimum difference between elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232930/finding-out-the-minimum-difference-between-elements-in-an-arrays)

[Find the minimum difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412170/find-the-minimum-difference-between-two-arrays)

[Find the minimum difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412170/find-the-minimum-difference-between-two-arrays)

[Dividing an array into two subsets of equal sizes having minimum difference in sum of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213689/dividing-an-array-into-two-subsets-of-equal-sizes-having-minimum-difference-in-s)

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-minimum-distance-between-two-numbers/

http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/10/15/find-the-minimum-difference/#comment-9146

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/391082/distance-between-two-closest-elements-in-an-array

Following is my program and my own attempt to try and find the "**Minimum difference between two elements within the array, any two pairs**", then let be there more than one pair of numbers which gives the same minimum difference numerically. I tried to change loops to count them differently and also tried to change the if condition clause for different results but finally ended up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                     //input output stream   
#include <cstdlib>
#include "math.h"                       //to be able to use math functions if any


using namespace std;

int main()

{

    
    int x=0,y=0,number1 = 0,number2 = 0,size1=0,mindiff = 0;
    int index = 0, count = 0, diff = 0;
    cout<<"enter the size of array you want \n\n";
    cin>>size1;
    int arr1[size1];
    cout<<"\n\n please enter elements of array \n\n";
    
    for (int i =0;i<size1;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr1[i];
    }
    for ( x=0;x<size1;x++ )
    {
        diff = 0;
        for ( y=0;y<size1;y++ )
        {
            diff = abs(arr1[x] - arr1[y]);
            if (diff<mindiff)
            {
                mindiff = diff;
                //index = x+1;
                number1 = arr1[x];
                number2 = arr1[y];
            }
        }
            
        }   


cout<<"\nthe elements amongst which the minimum difference was given are "<<number1<<" & "<<number2<<endl;
cout<<"the difference between them is "<<abs(mindiff)<<endl;
    
system("pause");
return 0;
}


//end of program
```

All the above references and lots more but could not find anyone that follows my perspective. I know that i may be doing something really silly/wrong out here because i get a maximum difference and not minimum difference.Where am I going wrong?
I anyways have to keep on assigning the new minimum every time a lower difference is found as written in the if condition statement right???

following is the output

enter the size of array you want

6

please enter elements of array

1
2
34345
7
8
9

the elements amongst which the minimum difference was given are 1 & 34345
the difference between them is 34344

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: What numbers did you use, what result did you expect, and what result did you get?

Comment: yes am editing the question now to post the output

Comment: sort array, find minimum.

Comment: my question is why cant we do it without sorting

Comment: Why is `diff=0` inside the loop?

Comment: @CodeMan you can, but it will be O(N^2), sorting will give you O(NlogN).

Comment: It amazes me that you use abs to report the result, but not in the calculation. I suggest you close this question, as it is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: yes but it also amazes me that by changing that it still gives me the same maximum difference result instead of minimum difference result.

Comment: @SashaMN that will be fine for now i just need to see if the logic works, so far it has not worked

Comment: Put a `cout` statement in your innermost loop: `cout << arr1[x] << " " << arr[y] << " " << diff << endl;`. This will tell you what is actually happening. And remove the `abs` from your final output code. And try it with **two** numbers, before you attempt six.

Comment: yes, that helps me identify the point at which my code works weird......thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the advice from Beta and also looking at the only answer that i found aligning with my code perspective, i came up with the following smal but critical edit of my own code above. Not much change but a very important and essential change.
PFB the code which indicates that fact that i had a logical error in not loading the difference value temporarily in a variable before exiting the innermost loop for the next iteration for comparing the absolute difference value.

```
#include <iostream>                             //input output stream   
#include <cstdlib>
//#include <vector>         not used            //to enable usage and implementation of vectors
#include "math.h"                               //to be able to do complex math functions if any
//#include <algorithm>      not used            //to be able to use max_element() and distance() functions on iterator.


using namespace std;

int main()

{

/*
first different variables for loop counters and 
size of array is taken in advanced instead of calculating during the program to reduce program time

*/

    int x=0,y=0,number1 = 0,number2 = 0,size1=0,mindiff = 0;
    int index = 0, count = 0, diff = 0;
    cout<<"enter the size of array you want \n\n";
    cin>>size1;
    int arr1[size1];
    cout<<"\n\n please enter elements of array \n\n";

    for (int i =0;i<size1;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr1[i];
    }
    for ( x=0;x<size1;x++ )
    {

        for ( y=0;y<size1;y++ )
        {
        if (x!=y)
/*
now load the difference in a variable named diff
and use a comparisional conditional statement to select
value of minimum difference
*/
            {
            diff = abs(arr1[x] - arr1[y]);
                if(count == 0)
                {
                    mindiff = diff;
                }
            else
                {
                    if (diff<mindiff)
                    {
                    cout<<diff<<" minimum difference "<<"\n";
                    mindiff = diff;
                    //index = x+1;
                    number1 = arr1[x];
                    number2 = arr1[y];
                    }
                }
            count++;
            }
        }

    }


cout<<"\nthe elements amongst which the minimum difference was given are "<<number1<<" & "<<number2<<endl;
cout<<"the difference between them is "<<abs(mindiff)<<endl;
cout<<endl<<endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

This lets me perceive that perspective of coding does work for this case. Sure it might be slow and inefficient but its a result.
gratitude to all for their time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **abs(x)** function to make sure that diff is positive. Otherwise, the difference between arr1[x]:5 and arr1[y]:10 (5-10=-5) will be smaller than the difference between arr1[x]:5 and arr1[y]:4 (5-4=1).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/

You also want to make sure that you never check with the same index, i.e. x=y.

Comment: oh yes that does help because it would otherwise report zero everytime.....but it still gives a maximum difference now am planing to use abs in the loop

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your algorithm a little bit (halving the comparisons, actually) by considering the underlying simmetry:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using std::cout;

// I'll use a struct to return the values
struct dif_t {
    int first;
    int second;
    int dif;
};

dif_t min_difference( const int *x, size_t n ) {
    dif_t min{0,0,0};
    min.dif = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        //remember that abs(x[i]-x[j])=abs(x[j]-x[i]) and x[i]-x[i]=0
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j ) {
            //          ^^^^^^^
            int dif = abs( x[i] - x[j] );
            if ( dif < min.dif ) {
                min.dif = dif;
                min.first = x[i];
                min.second = x[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main() {
    // I'll skip the input part
    int numbers[] = { 1, 20, 34345, 89, 7, 88 };

    dif_t edif = min_difference(numbers, sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int));

    std::cout << "The elements with the minimum difference are:\n"
        << edif.first << " and " << edif.second << '\n'
        << "The difference between them is:\n" << edif.dif << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to find all the pairs with the same minimum difference you can modify the previous program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;


struct dif_t {
    vector<pair<int,int>> pairs;
    int dif;
};

dif_t min_difference( const vector<int> &x ) {
    dif_t min;
    min.dif = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i ) {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < x.size(); ++j ) {
            int dif = abs( x[i] - x[j] );
            if ( dif > min.dif ) continue;
            // if the difference is less then the minimum, empties the container
            if ( dif < min.dif ) {
                min.dif = dif;
                min.pairs.clear();
            }
            // add the couple to the vector
            min.pairs.push_back(std::make_pair(x[i], x[j]));
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 4, 34345, 34346, 6, 89, 7, 88 };

    dif_t edif = min_difference(numbers);

    cout << "The elements with the minimum difference are:\n";
    // loop for each couple in the container
    for ( auto & c : edif.pairs ) {
        cout << c.first << " and " << c.second << '\n';
    }       
    cout << "The difference between them is:\n" << edif.dif << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
The elements with the minimum difference are:
1 and 2
34345 and 34346
6 and 7
89 and 88
The difference between them is:
1
```

If the number of elements is bigger, as others pointed out, you can sort the vector before calculating the differences, so you will minimize the comparison needed.

```
// this will change the original vector
dif_t min_diff_sorted( vector<int> &x ) {
    // erase the reference symbol  ^ if you want to sort a copy of the vector 
    dif_t min;
    min.dif = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    // usually sorting algorithms have N*logN complexity 
    std::sort( x.begin(), x.end() );

    // now that the vector is sorted we can compare the adiacent elements only.
    // This time I'll use two iterators to access the elements of the vector
    // ix will iter from the beginning of the vector to the last - 1 element
    // jx points to the element adjacent (+1) to ix
    for ( auto ix = x.begin(), jx = ix + 1;
            jx != x.end();      // stop condition
            ix = jx, jx++ ) {
        // the inner part doesn't change, it's only executed N-1 times 
        // instead of N*(N-1)/2                 
        int dif = abs( *ix - *jx );
        if ( dif > min.dif ) continue;
        if ( dif < min.dif ) {
            min.dif = dif;
            min.pairs.clear();
        }
        min.pairs.push_back(std::make_pair(*ix, *jx));
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: wholly chao Bob, my sincere gratitude for the effort, i needed the extended features...However i was trying to figure out a way to do the original task without using special libraries....But i like the extended improv....d|  d| d|

Comment: @CodeMan You're welcome. Please note that the "special libraries" are the C++ Standard Library, which is literally part of the language ;) You can use plain arrays, of course, (and try to implement a good sort) but that way is more error prone, and not so easy as you may think.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate mindiff at start as abs(arr1[0]-arr1[1]) and then proceed to calculate it inside the loop:

```
 // check whether array size is >=2 or not
    mindiff = abs(arr1[0]-arr1[1]);

    for ( x=0;x<size1;x++ )
    {
        for ( y=0;y<size1;y++ )
        {
           // do not calculate the difference of same number
            if(x!=y){
                diff = abs(arr1[x] - arr1[y]);
                if (diff<=mindiff)
                {
                    mindiff = diff;
                    number1 = arr1[y];
                    number2 = arr1[x];
                    cout<<number1<< ","<<number2<<endl;
                }
           }
        }
      }   

 cout<<"\nthe elements amongst which the minimum difference was given are "<<number1<<" & "<<number2<<endl;

cout<<"the difference between them is "<<abs(mindiff)<<endl;
```